# Visual Studio 2017 freezes and then crashes when I open a Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crash

I have a c# project(WinForms) with slight syntax errors and when I try to open it, Visual Studio immediately freezes and then exits/crashes.
I think it has something to do with the `System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler`  because if I don't include it, it doesn't crash.

What I did was not include the `System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler` and it didn't crash. But I can't figure out why it crashes with the `System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler` included.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace hiddenform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static hide hide = new hide();
        public event System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler keyhandler = new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(hide.handlekeys);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

I just can't figure out why VS2017 just crashes when I have the `System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler` included. It also didn't crash with the `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler`.

You can also find the complete Solution on [Github](https://github.com/thebear8/hiddenform) in case you need that.

Comment: HAve you tried to delete the .vs folder (quit VS before this) in the file-system and then restart the solution? BTW: Add a .gitignore to your project in order to avoid committing the .vs folder to your repo!

Comment: just to be sure: it crashes right after you *open the solution*, or when you build, or start debugging? please include all information about the crash you can get: error codes, call stacks, information from WER and event log.

Comment: `System.Windows.Input` is WPF, not sure if that's related to the problem but you're probably best suited sticking with Winforms entirely

Comment: Deleting the .vs folder just makes it crash on opening the file when the solution is already opened, not right when I open the Solution.

Comment: I added the errors from event manager on [github](https://github.com/thebear8/hiddenform/blob/master/errors.txt) in errors.txt (didnt want to post them all here because they're too many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler` is a method which is typically set in the "Designer" of a form, try implementing it there it should solve your problem!